# How to copy XML column to a table from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just created a new database and would like to copy data from my old database:

```
use database2

insert into DataTable (column1, column2, xmlcolumn)
    select column1, column2, xmlcolumn
    from database1.dbo.DataTable
```

And I get this error:

> Implicit conversion between XML types constrained by different XML schema collections is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

I tried `CONVERT(XML, xmlcolumn)` but I still get the same error.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Can you add an example with xmlschema for us to test

Comment: It would appear that your XML columns involved are "typed", e.g. have a XML schema associated with them - but a **different** XML schema - so you cannot just copy XML from one column (with schema A) to the other column (with schema B)

Comment: @marc_s both databases were created via same script, so they should be using same schema. Btw, after dropping the xml schema collection I am able to copy the column.